# Css calc not working in IE11 with linear gradient

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-calc

```css
*{
  margin:0; padding: 0;
}
body {
 background-color: orangered;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #fdfdff;
}
.tilt {
  position: relative;
}
.tilt:before {
  content: '';
    padding-top: 8.74887%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(5deg, #fdfdff calc(50% - 1px), transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="content tilt">

</div>
```

It seems that IE11 has some problems understanting calc() css property.

I am using calc with linear-gradient in this way:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(5deg, #fdfdff calc(50% - 1px), transparent 50%);
```

But when I use it as this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(5deg, #fdfdff, transparent 50%);
```

It works without problems.

And there is one more thing that I don't understand. When I inspect that property in IE11, turn it off and back on it works.

The whole point of using calc(50% - 1px) is that angle looks smoother, that is it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: IE is a little finicky with `calc` value inheritance. What is it inheriting 50% from? A more complete demo, like a [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: I've added and example to the post. Hope that it helps.

Comment: Per Caniuse.com, it seems IE11 doesn't support `calc` properly in generated content (which includes ::before/::after pseudo elements)

Comment: It does not happen in my IE11 when I run it in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/314hphyd/

Comment: What are you trying to calculate here? A new hex color value?

Comment: @Gerard No, `calc(50% - 1px)` calculates a [___color-stop___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Values) for the gradient

Comment: @LGSon you are right. 
I have solution but it is not perfect. I could use .ie11 class and added it as conditional part of html element and then make that color stop without calc(50% - 1px).

Comment: And you can also simply move the pseudo element up and/or down...it all comes down to what you need to achieve. If it is a slanted edge you are looking for, `transform: skew` or `transform: rotate` might be another option

Answer (score 3):

I found solution.
In my sass mixin I've added:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) { background: linear-gradient($angle, $color 50%, transparent 50%); }
```

Now it works as I wanted to.