# Solid Linear Gradient not behaving as expected on IE11

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create a diagonal background that is mostly white and has an orange strip on the end using SCSS / CSS. I have this working on most browsers using linear-gradient, but as always, IE is messing up and behaving weirdly.

Here's a pen of what I'm doing and the SCSS that goes with it: https://codepen.io/WDACDavy/pen/eyzRgq

```
$orange: #f25b2e;
$white: #FFFFFF;
body {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
.slash {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(162deg, $white 0%, $white calc(50% - 5px), $orange calc(50% - 4px), $orange calc(50% + 4px), transparent calc(50% + 5px), transparent);
}
```

The HTML body is simply a `<div class="slash"></div>` element.

This actually WORKS in the pen until I inspect it, then it gets all blurry.

[Blurry gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppz49.png)

Any ideas?

EDIT: To be clear, the above code is NOT working in IE11 on Windows 7. It appears blurry like in the example picture above. If you inspect the codepen you will see what I mean.

Comment: I don't understand. Everything I am trying to do is in the above question. It works in all browsers except Internet Explorer and I am asking why that is. The code is complete and you can verify it is occurring (I captured this in the screenshot).

Comment: You're right. I missed the html you posted. It looked too minimal.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44027789/css-calc-not-working-in-ie11-with-linear-gradient

Comment: Paulie, thanks for that. In the meantime, using that @media rule without calc() will have to do for IE users.